# How to Make CSS Hover Dropdown Menu Items Expand With Text

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a menu that will be fixed at the top of the page.  One of the menu choices is "TEAM", which will drop down when hovered on with all the people on the team.  The list of names will be generated dynamically.

The problem I am having is if the person's name is long, the dropdown menu item for that person won't expand with his/her name.  Instead it will display their name on 2 or more lines.

I've tried using min-width, width: 100% on the dropdown-content div, which is the div that contains all the dropdown buttons.

```
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 180px;
    width: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Nothing seems to work.  I've also tried giving the 'dropdown-content a' a width and/or min-width but I still can't get the buttons to expand with the name.

This is the JSFiddle example I created: https://jsfiddle.net/ebz24jc2/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap;`

```
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 180px;
    width: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: You sir, are amazing!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add `white-space: nowrap;` to the parent of the text you don't want to wrap.